# Soft keyboard not opening after setting textIsSelectable(true) in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

To make edittext selectable without showing soft keyboard, I had put `edittext.textIsSelectable(true)` attribute and I had hidden the soft keyboard.

When I try to open soft keyboard again, it not opening.

I tried setting `setFocusable(true)` in edittext but still keyboard not opening. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: use `edittext.requestFocus();` in your java code.

Comment: I tried but still not working

Answer (score 3):

By using the below code for EditText you can get the event for `Cut/Copy/Paste`
And you have to create editText like below.And you can hide the soft keyboard after event fired...

```
<com.example.textlink.EditTextMonitor
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:hint="EditText" />
```

Create one java file in your package...

```
public class EditTextMonitor extends EditText {
private final Context mcontext; // Just the constructors to create a new
                                // EditText...

public EditTextMonitor(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mcontext = context;
}

public EditTextMonitor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.mcontext = context;
}

public EditTextMonitor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.mcontext = context;
}

@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
    // Do your thing:
    boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
    // React:
    switch (id) {
    case android.R.id.cut:
        onTextCut();
        break;
    case android.R.id.paste:
        onTextPaste();
        break;
    case android.R.id.copy:
        onTextCopy();
    }
    return consumed;
}

/**
 * Text was cut from this EditText.
 */
public void onTextCut() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
            .getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Event of Cut!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Text was copied from this EditText.
 */
public void onTextCopy() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
            .getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Event of Copy!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Text was pasted into the EditText.
 */
public void onTextPaste() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
            .getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Event of Paste!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Comment: Hi Santhosh,
Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate it.
But the problem statement is when we select some text in edittext soft keyboard should not open. In your case after selecting cut, copy or paste only we can able to hide the soft keyboard. But in my case keyboard should be hidden before selecting cut,copy or paste.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without setting attribute `edittext.textIsSelectable(true)`

you can able to select the entered  text and copy it right, why don't you go blindly with the edittext with basic attributes

Comment: I don't want the keyboard to be open when I select some text in edittext that's why. I think this is the only way to hide keyboard without affecting selection.

If you know some other method to hide the keyboard when selecting the text, you are welcome to answer. :-)

Comment: I removed textSelectable and now it is working. Also text is select able without this property.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

Just override the `isTextSelectable()` method in Edittext.

If you want to open keyboard then return `super.isTextSelectable()`.

If you don't want to open keyboard then return `true`.

That's it. It worked for me.

Comment: Setting this property as false or even removing it from the XML is the samething.